# Windows Phone Facebook (OAuthException) (#1) An unknown error occurred

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a WP7 app using facebook SDK 5.4.1. I try to upload a photo to Facebook, but always get an error message "(OAuthException) (#1) An unknown error occurred".

Here is my code:

```
var app = new Facebook.FacebookApp(AuthKey);
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
   {
       {"message","test"},
       {"description","test2"}
   };
FacebookMediaObject media = new FacebookMediaObject
{
   FileName = "1",
   ContentType = "image/jpeg"
};
WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource("/Images/thumbnails/Color.png");
media.SetValue(wb.ToByteArray());
parameters.Add("source", media);
app.PostAsync("me/photos", parameters, new FacebookAsyncCallback(postResult));
```

I can post a message on FB wall using my app, but not for uploading photos(I tried to upload different sizes of photo). What can be wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `wb.toByteArray()` - you need to encode the image to JPEG before uploading it.

`Extensions.SaveJpeg()` is what you are looking for ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.extensions.savejpeg%28v=VS.92%29.aspx))

Comment: Thank you, you save me again :).